# Github search using regex

Tags: regex, git, github

Is there any way to search code in a github repo using regular expressions?

Currently, I clone the repo and search.

But I want to type something like

```
s/foo/gi
```

and find all occurances of foo in the code:

```
foo.create
foo.extend
fooBar
barFoo
bar.foo
```

Is this possible? Am I missing something [in the docs](https://help.github.com/categories/78/articles)?

Comment: This may be more suited for http://SuperUser.com, but I don't think it's totally out of place here.

Comment: For anyone interested, here's documentation for [Searching GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-github) and [Searching repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories).

Comment: So, I guess that means that it doesn't support regx.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan (and others). My understanding is that questions relating to programming tools are now on topic for this site.

Comment: **See also:** https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax **answering the question:** I wish I could just jump on github, search a repository with s/foo/g and be done with it. **No** (as of 2021-04)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it's a Git repo, why not just clone it locally, and then use [`git grep`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html) with one of it's regex options?:

```
git grep [-w | --word-regexp]
         [-E | --extended-regexp] [-G | --basic-regexp]
         [-P | --perl-regexp]
```

So maybe something along the lines of

```
$ git clone repo
$ git grep -w foo
```

Comment: Well, that is what I have been doing, but I wish I could just jump on github, search a repository with s/foo/g  and be done with it.  I guess that isn't possible.

Comment: "Why not just clone it locally" - some big public repos take a *long* time to clone. I've had time to search this question and read several pages on it, and compose this comment while waiting for git to finish cloning the TypeScript repo.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with [GitHub Code Search](https://cs.github.com/).

Comment: Regex in the code search docs (since it was strangely difficult to find):
https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#using-regular-expressions

Comment: And it's implemented with the rust regex crate:
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/9876#discussioncomment-1949013

Answer (score 0):

[Livegrep](https://github.com/livegrep/livegrep) allows for interactive regex search of ~gigabyte-scale source repositories.

Answer (score -1):

Using the keyword "OR"?

```
foo.create OR foo.extend OR fooBar OR barFoo OR bar.foo
```

*edit: Oops, I answer next to your needs. sorry.*

Comment: Though one way to do it, it necessitates knowing all the various ways to work it.  I will update ot make more accurate.