# Searching a github repo using regular expressions

Tags: search, github

I wanted to search my company's github source website using regular expressions. is that possible in anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github search using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595962/github-search-using-regex)

Comment: This is now possible with [GitHub Code Search](https://cs.github.com/).

Comment: [GitHub Code Search Regular Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#using-regular-expressions) ... specific to _code_ searches.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK you would need to set that up yourself. Github has its own [search syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/) with qualifiers you can add, but not full regex. The api uses the same syntax as the in-browser search.

Comment: "The api uses the same syntax as the in-browser search" Is that still true now that GitHub _does_ offer regex search in-browser (by wrapping the regex like `/regex/`)?

Comment: @MichaelChirico you are correct, the API and Browser-based search use different syntax rules. From the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code) "You only need to use the legacy code search syntax if you are using the code search API." So API searches use legacy search syntax which is more limited and does not allow regex.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that a [GitHub search is limited to the `master` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493853/6309) of your repos.

The easiest solution is to:

- clone your company's github source website
- do locally a [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep), which supports basic regexp or extended POSIX regexp (`git grep -E`)
- or a [pickaxe search (`git log --all -S...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928721/6309)
- or [`git rev-list --all|grep xxx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4468394/6309) which also allows for regexp